# Can I have multiple GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-attributes, vertex-array-object

So I was looking at [another SO question regarding the command glVertexAttribPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876647/understanding-glvertexattribpointer) and I ran into a slight confusion. The accepted answer to this question explains,

> But there's an additional implied piece of state that is also stored away for attribute 0 when you make the call: the data is read from the buffer currently bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER

This makes sense to me, but what if I have multiple buffers that are bound as `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`? How does the `glVertexAttribPointer()` method know which one to set the attributes of?

For example, in my code, I'm drawing a gradient triangle. To do this, I've created 2 VBOs, one with color data in an array and another with vertex locations.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    static const GLfloat points[] = {
    //data here
    };
    static const GLfloat colors[] = {
      //data here
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertexShaderData, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragShaderData, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    sp=glCreateProgram();
    glBindFragDataLocation(sp, 0, "outColor");
    glAttachShader(sp, vs);
    glAttachShader(sp, fs);
    glLinkProgram(sp);
    glUseProgram(sp);
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9);
```

When I call the command, where do I specify which buffer to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This makes sense to me, but what if I have multiple buffers that are bound as GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

That's not possible. When you bind a buffer (or any OpenGL object) to a target, it automatically unbinds whatever was there before.

[OpenGL object targets](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Usage) are like global variables. What happens when you set a global integer to 3? It's old value is gone.

`glVertexAttribPointer` will *always* use whatever buffer is *currently* bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. So in your first call, it will use `buffer`. In your second call, it will use `colorBuffer`.

This is why it is important to remember that `glVertexAttribPointer` operates on what is *currently* bound. Because even after you bind `colorBuffer`, and set it to be used by attribute 1, attribute 0 *still* receives its vertex data from `buffer`.

So while you cannot have multiple buffers bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, you *can* use multiple buffers as sources for your vertex data.